# TortoiseSVN Log Messages offline repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a local svn repo and the access to server is no longer available.
I cannot see the log offline although the .svn folder has several GB in size - When I choose the offline option, it shows "Unable to connect to a repository at URL '...'" and the dates "From:", "To:" are set to 1/1/1970 .
The Log Caching is enabled but there is nothing in the Cached Repositories.
Is there a way to see the log?

EDIT: Not GB but hundreds of MB

Comment: I suspect you're using the wrong terminology and you actually mean a remote repository. If TortoiseSVN did not cache log messages then there's no way to do it once the repository becomes unavailable.

Comment: I think the messages are there, the .svn/pristine contains a lot of *.svn-base files, amounting to several hundreds of MB.

Comment: I checked the pristine directory, there are only source files there, no messages. I checked the wc.db file too - there are no messages. It seems to be no way to get them offline.

Comment: Subversion is a centralised version control system. That kind of information is stored in the **repository**. What you have is a **working copy**. If you've lost the server permanently then you've basically lost all your history.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way as the .svn folder being the only source of information does not contains the log messages.